# "One or more of the requested capabilities are not supported." AWS FARGATE

Tags: aws-fargate

I'm getting "One or more of the requested capabilities are not supported." error when trying to mount a volume from Amazon EFS on AWS FARGATE.

Answer (score 62):

Edit your service and update "Platform version" to 1.4.0

You can do this in terraform by adding an optional variable [`platform_version`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#platform_version) to the `aws_ecs_service` resource

Comment: Can you share how the heck you figured that out? I am struggling with various vague errors, including that exact one, trying to start tasks that seem to leave no trace of useful clues.

Comment: @BrendonWhateley I googled it and this tweet popped up:  https://twitter.com/slipdexic/status/1271223532018634752 . Took me a while to find it too.

Comment: I don't understand why AWS does that to us

Comment: It happens if you update to 1.4.0 and try and roll back to 1.3.0

Answer (score 31):

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/containers/aws-fargate-launches-platform-version-1-4/) is the official AWS communication about the platform version 1.4.0

Here is an important quote:

> The primer blog post goes into more detail about the philosophy behind why we introduced Fargate platform versions and, for example, the practical reasons why we are not tagging platform version 1.4.0 as LATEST just yet.

The primer blog post is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/containers/aws-fargate-platform-versions-primer/). Keep the focus on this "critical" point:

> Starting with the introduction of this platform version (1.4.0), we will hold on moving the LATEST tag. We want to provide a runway for users that use LATEST as an additional precaution. This means that if you are deploying today using the tag LATEST to identify a Fargate platform version, the system will keep referencing platform version 1.3.0 for now (albeit, technically, the latest platform version available today is 1.4.0).
>
> These users could either start experimenting with 1.4.0 by explicitly deploying to it or wait until we move the tag LATEST to point to platform version 1.4.0. [Updated on 6/17/2020] We plan to make this change in the May 2020 time frame We plan to make this change at some point in Q3/2020, thus giving customers [Updated on 6/17/2020] about a month a few months to test 1.4.0 before it gets tagged as LATEST. Expect a formal announcement for this change.
>
> This is intended to give users a window of time to test 1.4.0 without being forced to use it if they use the tag LATEST. We do not anticipate disruption but we decided to be conservative.

That's why you should use, **at the time of writing**, version **1.4.0**, instead of **LATEST** in order to use AWS EFS.

Comment: Good to know! Just the May 2020 time frame didn't hold, it's March 2021 and we still have to explicitly select 1.4.0 if we want the "latest" version ;-)